# Scala: subclassing with factories

Tags: scala, traits

Let's say I've got two traits, one of them being a factory for another:

```
trait BaseT {
  val name: String
  def introduceYourself() = println("Hi, I am " +name)
  // some other members ...
}
trait BaseTBuilder {
  def build: BaseT
}
```

Now, I want to extend BaseT:

```
trait ExtendedT extends BaseT {
  val someNewCoolField: Int
  override def introduceYourself() = {
    super.introduceYourself()
    println(someNewCoolField)
  }
  // some other extra fields
```

Let's say I know how to initialize the new fields, but I'd like to use `BaseTBuilder` for initializing superclass members. Is there a possibility to create a trait that would be able to instantiate `ExtendedT` somehow? This approach obviously fails:

```
trait ExtendedTBuilder { self: TBuilder =>
  def build: ExtendedT = {
    val base = self.build()
    val extended = base.asInstanceOf[ExtendedT] // this cannot work
    extended.someNewCoolField = 4  // this cannot work either, assignment to val
    extended
  }
  def buildDifferently: ExtendedT = {
    new ExtendedT(4)  // this fails, we don't know anything about constructors of ExtendedT
  }
  def build3: ExtendedT = {
    self.build() with {someNewCoolField=5} //that would be cool, but it cannot work either
  }
}
```

I'd like to have such a set of traits (or objects) that when someone supplies concrete implementation of `BaseT` and `BaseTBuilder` I could instantiantiate `ExtendedT` by writing:

```
val extendedBuilder = new ConcreteBaseTBuilder with ExtendedTBuilder
val e: ExtendedT = extendedBuilder.build
```

`ExtendedT` could contain a field of type `BaseT`, but then it would require manually proxying all the necessary methods and fields, which is in my opinion a violation of DRY principle. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

How about create ExtendBaseT instance in your ExtendBaseTBuilder

```
trait ExtendBaseTBuilder { self : BaseTBuilder =>
  def build: ExtendBaseT = {
    new ExtendBaseT {
      val someNewCoolField: Int = 3
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This way we're discarding job done by `BaseTBuilder` entirely, which is bad (`BaseT` can have some abstract members, that `BaseTBuilder` fills in). Moreover, someone could say `class TurboBuilder extends BaseTBuilder with AnotherBuilder { def build: BaseT with AnotherT = ... }`, so that `TurboBuilder` produces objects of type `BaseT with AnotherT`. Then, we'd like `(new TurboBuilder with ExtendedTBuilder).build` to be of type `ExtendedT with AnotherT`, which won't happen.